# How to use query strings along with wordpress pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, pagination

I'm having a slight problem integrating this into Wordpress as I am somewhat still new at using PHP. On this Wordpress theme there are multiple posts that need to load different ad code for promoters to use.

For example, `/story1/?id=matt` loads different ad code than `/story1/?id=john`.

This works great for the front pages of stories, however it is quickly ruined when the pagination takes effect. Instead of continuing to load that ad code, I go from `/story1/?id=matt` to `/story1/2`. The pagination takes effect and the query string does not carry.

This could be an absolute "nooby" question but it's something I really can't seem to figure out. I've put a good amount of research into this and nothing I do can seem to accomplish carrying the query string. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you need to do is use a little JavaScript to read in the query string on the current page and append it to your paginated links. Here's one way to do that (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Gets the query string
    var query_string = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?'));

    //Appends query string to each pagination link
    $('a.pagination-link').each(function () {
         var href = $(this).attr('href');
         $(this).attr('href', href + query_string);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

In general, you want your JavaScript in the footer of your website, or in an external file. If you only need the script for certain pages, then putting it in the appropriate file is fine. First things first, in order to use the above you need to make sure that you've got jQuery included in your website. Check your `<head>` on the finished page for something like `<script ... jquery.min.js>`. If it's not there, add the following line to your `header.php` file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, either in `footer.php` or the file that you need, copy and paste the above. Make sure that you have set the `class` on the links you need to add pagination to to `pagination-link`, otherwise the script will not add the query string to them.

They should look like:

```
<a href="http://link/to/next/page" class="pagination-link">Next</a>
```

or something similar.

Comment: How would I go about integrating this? I've tried placing it in my single.php file, but doesn't seem to be working. Really a big noobie when it comes to javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Hey there. So I tried this in just a test file off of wordpress and it works perfectly. Just some issues with the format of the pagination, but I think that is stuff I can figure out. I've confirmed that the concept behind the code works. Can't tell you how much I appreciate it! Thanks man.